# Whats the absolute best armor configuration for Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've looked at another article about this, and it didn't help me too much. The article just left me wondering if it's the same in Bedrock, and is it outdated.

Whats the absolute best armor configuration for Minecraft Bedrock?

Comment: The 'what is the best x' question format is not ..the best.. for Stack Exchange, but I can imagine there is only one right answer to this (and I think you got it). Can you edit your question to somehow limit potential answers? Describing the situations the armor should be 'best' for, the material, the enchantments, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

**Netherite Helmet:**

- Respiration 3
- Aqua Afinity
- Protection 4
- Unbreaking 3
- Mending

**Netherite Chestplate:**

- Protection 4
- Unbreaking 3
- Mending

**Netherite Leggings:**

- Protection 4
- Unbreaking 3
- Mending

**Netherite Boots:**

- Depth Strider 3
- Feather Falling 4
- Soul Speed 3
- Protection 4
- Unbreaking 3
- Mending

You don't *have* to have all the armour to be Netherite, but I highly recommend using it.

Comment: Netherite is better because it grants knockback resistance